# Scrollable div take up remaining height (Bootstrap 4 Flexbox grid system)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Before enabling flexbox support in Bootstrap 4 Alpha 3, my codes work well:

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/qap3o59f/)

However, after enabling flexbox support, I cannot make it work. If there is a way using [Bootstrap 4 built-in Flexbox grid system features](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/), that will be best!

[Not working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/wqk4ndme/2/)

**html**

```
<div class="container wrapper">
  <div class="row header">
      header
  </div>

  <div class="row content">
      content: fill remaining space and scroll<br>
      x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
      x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
      x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
      x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
      x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
  </div>

  <div class="row footer">
      footer
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapper {
  height: 20rem;
  display: flex;      /* if remove this, the style will be correct, but won't scroll */
  flex-flow: column;  /* if remove this, the style will be correct, but won't scroll */
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
}

.content {
  background: gold;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight change in your *CSS* will help you achieve the same with *Bootstrap 4* with *flex* enabled:
By default in *Bootstrap 4* it changes default properties of famous class `.row` to:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: -0.9375rem;
    margin-left: -0.9375rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

i.e. why your structure wasn't the same as it was before, all you need to do is to change its *CSS* back to the previous one as:

### CSS

```
.wrapper {
  height: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.row {
    display: block;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.row:before, 
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.row:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Here's the updated [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/wqk4ndme/5)

Comment: thanks, but if there is a way to not overwrite bootstrap css, that will be great

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @vivekkupadhyay, another way, just add `display: block;` to header and footer.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/kzzeg659/)

**html**

```
<div class="container wrapper">
  <div class="row header">
      header
  </div>

  <div class="row content">
      content: fill remaining space and scroll<br>
      x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
      x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
      x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
      x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
      x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
  </div>

  <div class="row footer">
      footer
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapper {
  height: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
  display: block;
}

.content {
  background: gold;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  display: block;
}
```